# Selector Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Buenas estoy intentando hacer una consulta a una base de datos con AJAX una vez que el usuario haya introducido valores en 3 input. La consulta debe meter los resultados en el datalist de un 4º input.
El problema lo tengo en el selector, lo he hecho anidándolos de manera que si los rellenas los 3 en orden hace correctamente la consulta AJAX pero si los haces desordenados (Ej: introduces valor para el 2º input y luego para el 1º) no lo realiza correctamente. ¿Cómo evito eso?

```
$("#clinica").on("input", function () {
            $("#medico").on("input", function () {
                $("#fecha").on("input", function () {
                   $.get("cambio_fecha.php", { clinicaHora: $('#clinica').val(),
                         medicoHora: $('#medico').val(),
                         fechaHora: $('#fecha').val()}, function (data) {
                               $("#opcionesHoras").empty();
                               $("#opcionesHoras").append(data);
                    });
                });
            });
```

Comment: No entiendo que es lo que quieres hacer ni que es lo que estás intentando, ¿puedes explicar mejor tu problema?

Comment: Simplemente quiero un selector de jquery que al introducir valores en 3 input en cualquier orden de inserción realice una función, el selector que he posteado hace  eso mismo que quiero pero cuando introduces valores en el orden #clinica -> #medico -> #fecha       (Añado todo el código en el post por si se entiende mejor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que esto te puede servir

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $(document).on('input', '#clinica, #medico, #fecha', function(){
    
     const cli = $('#clinica').val();
     const med = $('#medico').val();
     const fec = $('#fecha').val();
     
     if(cli != '' && med != '' && fec != ''){
      $('.result').html(cli + '<br />' + med + '<br />' + fec);
      // Hacer AJAX o lo que sea que necesitas
     }
    
  })
  
})
```

```css
.result{
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 161px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="clinica" placeholder="Clinica" /><br />
<input type="text" id="medico" placeholder="Médico" /><br />
<input type="text" id="fecha" placeholder="Fecha" /><br />
<div class="result"></div>
```